# Facebook app request dialog no longer sends notifications to users

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-app-requests, fb.ui

Last year, when our Facebook canvas app sent an app request using the FB.ui request dialog API, the request showed up in 3 places for the recipient(s):

- the notification jewel was updated
- on the upper right
- in the App Center

It appears that Facebook has removed the notification when you send someone an app request. I've tested this on two different apps and sending an app request does not result in a notification being sent to the recipient.

Two questions:

1. Can anyone verify that this is the current behavior?
2. When did this change? (Is there a breaking change description that references this?)

Comment: Correct, actual "notifications" when requests are sent to friends no longer correct. And for good reason, those things were freaking annoying.

Comment: Docs: "Requests that are Invites (the recipient user has not installed the app) do not display the message parameter and are categorized differently in the Apps and Games Dashboard." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/#user_to_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely WAS a bug per: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/532388000129311

It appears to be resolved now. A pretty heinous breakage on the part of the Facebook platform, if you ask me.